# Python: How can I find all strings matching any of the multiple patterns given

Tags: python, search, grep

I am new to Python and have been trying to find all the strings which match multiple patterns. I did some google search and found some posts which suggest to compile all the patterns into one. However they were using the `re.search()` function which only returns the first matched instance. I need to search all instances of strings which match any of the patterns in the order of their occurrence. Any direction/suggestion is welcome.

More specifically I am looking for something similar to this grep command

```
grep -i "[0-9' '-:A-Za-z].* ERROR.*Job failed\|Caused by:\|^      *at\|ERROR\|more$" <file-name>
```

Comment: There is also the re.findall, which finds all instances. See the documentation for python's regex https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.findall(combined_regex, your_string)` is probably what you're looking for.

If you plan on doing this many times in the same program, consider compiling the regex as follows for better performance:

```
compiled = re.compile(combined_regex)
results = compiled.findall(your_string)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am facing another issue and the command is only returning the match. Is there a way to return the entire line containing the match. This is what I am doing. pattern_strings =['[0-9" "-:A-Za-z].*ERROR.*Job run failed', 'Caused by:','^        *at','ERROR','more$'] ; pattern_string = '|'.join(pattern_strings); pattern = re.compile(pattern_string);results = pattern.findall(<my_multi line string>)

Comment: In that case, looping over lines via `splitlines` is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you're looking for smth like this:

```
import re

l_string="""gfrwrfr
gerqgeq
ERROR gferagqe
hello ERROR
smth more
more smth
Caused by: gferg
"""

pattern_strings =['[0-9" "-:A-Za-z].*ERROR.*Job run failed', 'Caused by:','^ *at','ERROR','more$']
pattern_string = '|'.join(pattern_strings)
pattern = re.compile(pattern_string)

for line in l_string.split("\n"):
    result = pattern.search(line)
    if result:
        print result.string
```

But of course, as we're already in the loop over lines, we can print line instead of match_obj.string.

Program output:

```
$  ./multiple_re.py
ERROR gferagqe
hello ERROR
smth more
Caused by: gferg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [multi_pattern_search](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multi_pattern_search). Example follows.

```
from multi_pattern_search import MultiPatternSearch

search = MultiPatternSearch()

search.add_keyword("foo")
search.add_keyword("bar")

print search.exist("apple tree foo john doe")

for k, v in search.count("apple tree foo bar foobar john doe").iteritems():
    print k, v
```